# How to sort MySQL ResultSet by Custom Field?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

Following is the schema and data:

```
Create table tblTestSorting (col int);
INSERT INTO tblTestSorting VALUES(2), (5), (3), (6), (4), (7), (1)
```

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT col, 5-col AS 'extra' FROM tblTestSorting ORDER BY 'extra';
```

I want to get the result sorted by 'extra' column, but
This query does not give me result sorted by 'extra' column..

How to achieve this..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT col, (5 - col) AS extra
FROM tblTestSorting 
ORDER BY extra;
```

Check [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb3f48/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
| COL | EXTRA |
|-----|-------|
|   7 |    -2 |
|   6 |    -1 |
|   5 |     0 |
|   4 |     1 |
|   3 |     2 |
|   2 |     3 |
|   1 |     4 |
```

Answer (score 0):

give the order by type(asc or desc)..
try this..

```
SELECT col, 5-col AS extra FROM tblTestSorting ORDER BY col ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

two ways

```
SELECT col, 5-col AS 'extra' FROM tblTestSorting ORDER BY 5-col;


SELECT col, 5-col AS 'extra' FROM tblTestSorting ORDER BY 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 SELECT col, 5-col AS 'extra' FROM tblTestSorting ORDER BY 'extra' ASC
```

or

```
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT col, 5-col AS 'extra' FROM tblTestSorting) as t ORDER BY t.'extra' ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1

> select * from (SELECT col, 5-col AS 'extra' FROM tblTemp) order by extra

or solution 2

> SELECT col, 5-col AS `extra` FROM tblTemp order by `extra`